# How do you disable auto-closing JSX tags in VSCode?

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Seems like a new feature - when I type `<View>` it turns into `<View></View>`. Can't imagine why anyone would want that but witholding judgement, how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 19):

You can turn it off with the following setting:

```
"javascript.autoClosingTags": false
```

Comment: Also there is a separate setting for tsx (TypeScript) files: `"typescript.autoClosingTags": false`

Comment: Worth mentioning that I realized that these settings are available through the GUI.  File->Preferences->Settings->Search for the key.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's a nice feature but if you want to turn it off completely then you can hit the gear icon on left-bottom side corner and go to `settings` > search `editor.autoClosingBrackets`. If this is set to true, make it `false`. This is the default configuration settings you can override but in case you've installed some other plugin (related to React) then let me know.

Comment: I actually already have this turned to false - I don't think I've installed any extensions that would tamper with it