# Disable auto closing tags just for components only and but not for empty tags in react

Tags: reactjs, format, jsx

i want to achieve this,

[How do you disable auto-closing JSX tags in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939158/how-do-you-disable-auto-closing-jsx-tags-in-vscode)

but i want to still have empty tags (<></>) to auto complete, how?